# Set Size for UIButton with new iOS15 Configuration Approach

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton, ios15

My goal is to add button to the right hand side of a section header in a UITableView.

However, when I made my new target iOS15, I found that I had to adopt UIButton configuration to set the padding to the add icon in the button. The problem is that, configuration doesn't seem to have a "frame" property and passing a configuration to a button then setting its frame builds to show no button at all.

My new, faulty code is:

```
func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let frame = tableView.frame
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))  // create custom view

    let sectionName = hasSections ? sectionTasks[section].sectionName : nil
    if sectionName != nil {
        let view = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        ... // Label config, skipping here
        let tableWidth = tableView.frame.width
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: tableWidth, height: 30)
        headerView.addSubview(label)
    }
            
    // My faulty button
    var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    buttonConfig.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
    buttonConfig.image = UIImage(named: "add_AsTemplate")
    let xPos = tableView.frame.width-40-15
    let button = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    button.tag = section
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BaseTaskListVC.sectionNewTask_BtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)  // add selector called by clicking on the button
    headerView.addSubview(button)
    
    return headerView
}
```

My original button code (skipping context of parent function):

```
let xPos = tableView.frame.width-40-15
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
button.tag = section
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5  )
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "add_AsTemplate"), for: UIControl.State.normal) 
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BaseTaskListVC.sectionNewTask_BtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside) 
headerView.addSubview(button)
```

I've read the Apple documentation but it doesn't seem to address this explicitly. All the other SO threads on this show how to use configuration but not configuration + frame.

Original code:

[image: Original code at runtime]

With new configuration approach:

[image: With new configuration approach]

Lastly, I've tried the suggested answer:

```
var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
buttonConfig.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)

var theImage: UIImage
if let img = UIImage(named: "add_AsTemplate") {
    theImage = img
} else if let img = UIImage(systemName: "plus") {
    // I don't have your "add_AsTemplate" image, so I'll use a SF Symbol
    theImage = img
} else {
    fatalError("Could not load a button image!")
}
buttonConfig.image = theImage
let button = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig)

button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headerView.addSubview(button)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor),
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15.0),
])
```

Which produced this result:

[image: Image overflowing its bounds]

Answer (score 0):

You are not **required** to use the "new" `UIButton.Configuration` button style... you can continue to use the "old" button class.

However, in either case, you should be using auto-layout / constraints, rather than setting the `.frame`.

For example:

```
    let button = UIButton()
    
    var theImage: UIImage
    if let img = UIImage(named: "add_AsTemplate") {
        theImage = img
    } else if let img = UIImage(systemName: "plus") {
        // I don't have your "add_AsTemplate" image, so I'll use a SF Symbol
        theImage = img
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not load a button image!")
    }
    button.setImage(theImage, for: .normal)

    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5  )

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    headerView.addSubview(button)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15.0),
    ])
```

or, using `UIButton.Configuration`:

```
    var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    buttonConfig.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)

    var theImage: UIImage
    if let img = UIImage(named: "add_AsTemplate") {
        theImage = img
    } else if let img = UIImage(systemName: "plus") {
        // I don't have your "add_AsTemplate" image, so I'll use a SF Symbol
        theImage = img
    } else {
        fatalError("Could not load a button image!")
    }
    buttonConfig.image = theImage
    let button = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig)

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    headerView.addSubview(button)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15.0),
    ])
```

Both give this result (the yellow rectangle is "simulating" your table header view), regardless of the actual width:

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit**

Here is a complete, runnable example. Just assign `DemoTableViewController` as the class of a table view controller:

```
class MySectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    // closure for "add" button tap
    var addTapClosure: (() -> ())?
    
    var theButton: UIButton!
    var theLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        buttonConfig.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
        
        var theImage: UIImage
        if let img = UIImage(named: "add_AsTemplate") {
            theImage = img
        } else if let img = UIImage(systemName: "plus") {
            // I don't have your "add_AsTemplate" image, so I'll use a SF Symbol
            theImage = img
        } else {
            fatalError("Could not load a button image!")
        }
        buttonConfig.image = theImage
        
        theButton = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig, primaryAction: UIAction() { _ in
            self.addTapClosure?()
        })
        
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(theButton)

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // this avoids auto-layout warnings
        let b = theButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        b.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            theButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            b,

            theButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            theButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        ])

        // so we can see the header framing
        contentView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}

class MyDemoCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var theButton: UIButton!
    var theLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var theSubLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier);
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        buttonConfig.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
        
        var theImage: UIImage
        if let img = UIImage(named: "check_AsTemplate") {
            theImage = img
        } else if let img = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill") {
            // I don't have a "check_AsTemplate" image, so I'll use a SF Symbol
            theImage = img
        } else {
            fatalError("Could not load a button image!")
        }
        buttonConfig.image = theImage
        
        theButton = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig)
        
        theLabel.textColor = .darkGray
        theSubLabel.textColor = .gray
        theLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15.0, weight: .regular)
        theSubLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .regular)

        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theSubLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        theButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(theSubLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(theButton)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            
            theSubLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 6.0),
            theSubLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 24.0),
            theSubLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            theButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            theButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
            theButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0),
        ])
        
    }
}

struct MyTask {
    var title: String = "Example Task"
    var subTitle: String = "Tap to update this to a real task"
}

class DemoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var theData: [[MyTask]] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(MyDemoCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        tableView.register(MySectionHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "h")
        tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
        
        // create sample data - 5 sections, each with one task
        for _ in 1...5 {
            var secData: [MyTask] = []
            secData.append(MyTask())
            theData.append(secData)
        }
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData[section].count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! MyDemoCell
        let d = theData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        c.theLabel.text = d.title
        c.theSubLabel.text = d.subTitle
        return c
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let v = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "h") as! MySectionHeaderView
        v.theLabel.text = "Header for Section: \(section)"
        
        v.addTapClosure = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.theData[section].append(MyTask(title: "Added", subTitle: "via header button tap"))
            self.tableView.reloadSections([section], with: .automatic)
        }
        return v
    }
    
}
```

Should look like this (after I added two additional rows to section 1):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, using "imageEdgeInsets" gets a warning "imageEdgeInsets" was deprecated in iOS15..."

I also run the version using UIButton Configuration and the image overflowed from its bounds and became 70% of the screen height. I tried setting a Y constraint and a top alignement instead of setting w:40, h:40 but that didn't work.

Comment: @Dave - Deprecated does not mean "cannot use" ... and you'll note the warning states the property will be ignored *when using UIButtonConfiguration*. Anyway, I don't know what you might have done differently than the sample code I posted, so see the **Edit** to my answer for a complete example.